# What to do with avocado seed at this point?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, containers, sunlight, avocado

I have an avocado seed that's sprouting. What should I do now so that the seed continues growing at a healthy rate?

It will eventually grow in a pot.

[image]

Comment: Put it in a pot with fresh potting soil and keep it moist. Give it sunlight too.

Comment: yup, do what b.nota said...keep it moist but don't keep the entire body of soil wet.  Just an inch deep and keep checking to make sure the soil is not soaked just moist...an inch below the roots? An inch below your seed.  I would start with a shallow clay pot 3" deep, 4" diameter.  Once roots begin to grow you should be able to soak the entire body of soil (no rocks or gravel below the soil please) and allow to dry out somewhat before watering again.  Get a simple balanced fertilizer and only use half the amount they recommend.  Osmocote is the simplest and lasts  4 to 6 months.